# Geotools create shapefile in memory

Tags: shapefile, geojson, convert, java

Is it possible to convert between shapefile and geojson using geotools without access to file system? I have that restriction in my web app, but I need to create shapefile as byte array and then do something with that. Unfortunately I only found a way where I need to specify new data store based on file path.

Answer (score 2):

Despite its nice sounding name a "shapefile" is not a single file but a whole bunch (at least 3 probably not more than 10) of related files which share a common base name. This is why GeoTools requires a URL pointing to the base file (`x.shp`) and then picks up the other files it needs based on that location.

If you are building your shapefile in memory why not just build a [FeatureCollection](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html) and then dump that out as [GeoJSON](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/geojsonstore) (or any other supported [DataStore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/index.html))

Note: You will need to be working on master for the GeoJSON store as I haven't backported it (no demand yet).

**Update based on comment**

With some luck you can access a zipped shapefile using something like this:

```
URL zip = DataUtilities.fileToURL(new File("../../data/coast.zip"));
URL shape = new URL("jar:"+zip+"!/110m_coastline.shp");
Map<String, URL> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("url", shape);
DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params );
String name = ds.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureSource source = ds.getFeatureSource(name);
System.out.println(name+" has "+source.getCount(Query.ALL)+" features");
```

It's left as an exercise for the reader as to how you determine the contents of the zip file, but I guess you can do it using the Zip classes in `java.util`.

Comment: The thing is that I need to implement shapefile export/import functionality. User will upload zip file that needs to be exported as geojson, or user will click export and then I need to create shapefile from the geospatial data from the database and then return the zip file

Comment: see if the updated code helps

Comment: but it again seems to be accessing the file system? I have a restriction to not use the file system and to not operate with local files. I should only use ram memory

Comment: that is just because that is where my file lives, you must have some reference to the zip file somewhere. Anyway this is wandering off topic.